# Load more functionality using SwiftUI

Tags: scrollview, swiftui, hstack

i have used ScrollView with HStack, now i need to load more data when user reached scrolling at last.

```
var items: [Landmark]
```

i have used array of items which i am appeding in `HStack` using `ForEach`

```
ScrollView(showsHorizontalIndicator: false) {
    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(self.items) { landmark in
            CategoryItem(landmark: landmark)
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best possible solution to manage load more in **SwiftUI** without using custom action like loadmore button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's better to use ForEach and List for this purpose

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var textfieldText: String = "String "
    private let chunkSize = 10
    @State var range: Range<Int> = 0..<1

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(range) { number in
                Text("\(self.textfieldText) \(number)")
            }
            Button(action: loadMore) {
                Text("Load more")
            }
        }
    }

    func loadMore() {
        print("Load more...")
        self.range = 0..<self.range.upperBound + self.chunkSize
    }
}
```

In this example each time you press load more it increases range of State property. The same you can do for BindableObject.
If you want to do it automatically probably you should read about PullDownButton(I'm not sure if it works for PullUp)

**UPD:**
As an option you can download new items by using onAppear modifier on the last cell(it is a static button in this example)

```
var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(range) { number in
                Text("\(self.textfieldText) \(number)")
            }
            Button(action: loadMore) {
                Text("")
                }
                .onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: 10)) {
                        self.loadMore()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Keep in mind, that dispatch is necessary, because without it you will have an error saying "Updating table view while table view is updating). Possible you may using another async way to update the data

Comment: No i don't want to add button i just want to detect last view is now visible if it's visible then i will load more data

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It's works fine as you said only user tap on button but need to check how it would be done without button

Comment: Thanks @DevFav it will only increase rang. How can we add view?

Comment: @PinkeshGjr Just Run it. It will increase range, but range is a `@State` variable for the List, so updating the range the List will be reload. You just need to replace the range with your var items: [Landmark]

Comment: Thanks let me check once

Comment: @PinkeshGjr but is the button visible all the time?

Comment: @zerohedge yes logic is working fine so we can also display activity instead of button

Comment: @PinkeshGjr - so you are displaying the display activity conditionally on `onAppear`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep using List with `Data` instead of `Range`, you could implement the next script:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var items: [Landmark]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.items) { landmark in
                CategoryItem(landmark: landmark)
                   .onAppear {
                      checkForMore(landmark)
                   }
            }
        }
    }

    func checkForMore(_ item: LandMark) {
       guard let item = item else { return }

       let thresholdIndex = items.index(items.endIndex, offsetBy: -5)
        if items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id }) == thresholdIndex {
           // function to request more data
            getMoreLandMarks()
        }
    }
}
```

You should work in a ViewModel and separate the logic from the UI.

Credits to Donny Wals: [Complete example](https://www.donnywals.com/implementing-an-infinite-scrolling-list-with-swiftui-and-combine/)