# Load more functionality from json data using SwiftUI

Tags: json, foreach, swiftui, load

The idea from this question answered here [Load more functionality using SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489712/load-more-functionality-using-swiftui/56493491#56493491) does not include the option if you are getting your ForEach data from a json data source. With the code below what is the best way to achieve the required result?

```
Group {

    HStack {
        Text("Recommended Events")
           .font(.title3)
           .foregroundColor(.white)
           .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    
          Spacer()
                                    
           Button(action: {
            
           }) {
             Text("Show all")
               .font(.title3)
               .foregroundColor(Color.white)
               .fontWeight(.bold)
               }
           }
            .padding(15)

    ForEach(recommendeds) { recommended in
                                    NavigationLink(destination: RecommendedEventsDetailView(recommended: recommended)) {
                                    RecommendedEventsView(recommended: recommended)
                                    }
                                }

}
```

Comment: The [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) have examples within them on how to do this. If you download the sample code for the larger projects you will find examples

Comment: I went through the tutorials it is still different because it is only for toggle not a load more button. I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489712/load-more-functionality-using-swiftui but i am having problems with where to include the range option.                                                                       ForEach(hotspot) { hotspoties in
                            NavigationLink(destination: HotSpotsDetailView(hotspots: hotspoties)) {
                                HotSpotsItemView(hotspots: hotspoties)
                            }
                        }

Comment: Range? Nothing about your code talks about range. Are you talking about filtering maybe?

Comment: The range i am talking about is in the answer to this question that was asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489712/load-more-functionality-using-swiftui. I tried using it in my code but could not figure out how to use the range because my data is coming from a local json file.

Comment: You should look into `.filter` that could be a range of `indices` of your array

Answer (score 0):

Use the swift Codable protocol.
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-convert-json-into-swift-objects-using-codable
You’d have to define a swift struct and decode the json and put the decoded json as the value of an instance of the struct.

Comment: I am using the Codable Bundle Extension because i have a lot of json data

Comment: extension Bundle {
    func decode<T: Codable>(_ file: String) -> T {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in Bundle")
        }
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load \(file) in Bundle")
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        guard let decodedData = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) in Bundle")
        }
        return decodedData
    }
}